# Как сделать обрезку участка изображения в js?

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать подобную обрезку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть классная библиотека cropperjs: https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/
Там есть примеры и много настроек. На сервер можно оправлять уже вырезаную часть картинки, но безопасней делать обрезку на сервере, могу дать пример на laravel.

Comment: Если будет доступна область обрезки, то можно и на сервере

Comment: `const cropData = JSON.stringify(this.cropperInstance.getData(true))` Потом добавляю данные в FormData(то что отправлять на сервер): `this.avatarFormData.append('cropInfo', cropData)` На сервере есть библиотека для обрезки, делаю так: `Image::make($file)->crop(
            $cropInfo['width'],
            $cropInfo['height'],
            $cropInfo['x'],
            $cropInfo['y']
        );`

Comment: Спасибо, но мне надо устранить из этой библиотеки (cropperjs) возможность увеличивать и уменьшать изображение( фото должно быть фикс размера

Comment: Чтобы зума не было? Там много настроек, вот мои натсройки для аватарки:               
              `aspectRatio: 1, 
              viewMode: 1,
              zoomable: false,
              zoomOnTouch: false,
              zoomOnWheel: false`

Comment: всё, пасиб большое

Comment: я видать криво пишу эти настройки, zoomable: false; не пашет/ Cropper.zoomable: false; не пашет /Cropper.zoomable: (false); не пашет

Comment: new Cropper(image, options) Вот страница с кучей примеров: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/tree/master/examples

Comment: Как показывают миниатюры которые получатся после этого?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80852/discussion-between---and--).

Comment: Я слишком аутист, вроде маленький уровень для чатов)) нет полей ввода и тп) ...Да, именно эти изображения

Comment: Передай событие crop в котором можно отслеживать перемещение и зименение размеров рамки. Покажу на своем коде, у меня на фреймворке vue поэтому может быть запутано. В чат скинул

Comment: пасиб большое))